# Unity2D move RectTransform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The RectTransform is within a Canvas-HUD drawn in 'Space - Overlay', it actually receives the pointer/touch events, it also places the RectTransform at the right position it's just that the sprite isn't moving.

Here' the code that I put in my Update() function:

```
foreach (Touch t in Input.touches) { // check all the touches
    if (t.position.x >= Screen.width/2) { // if it's on the right half of the screen
        if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Began) { // if has just began pressing
            aimCenter = t.position; // set position
            Vector2 pos = new Vector2 (aimCenter.x / (float)Screen.width,aimCenter.y / (float)Screen.height); // calculate anchor position
            actionHandler.SetPosition (pos.x - .08f, pos.y - .14f, pos.x + .08f, pos.y + .14f); // apply anchor position (the function just sets anchorMax and anchorMin, then sets offsets to 0
            actionHandler.gameObject.SetActive (true); // make visible
        }
    }
    if (canMove && t.position.x < Screen.width/2) { // same as above but for the left half of the screen
        if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
            movCenter = t.position;
            Vector2 pos = new Vector2 (t.position.x / Screen.width, t.position.y / Screen.height);
            directionHandler.SetPosition (pos.x - .08f, pos.y - .14f, pos.x + .08f, pos.y + .14f);
            directionHandler.gameObject.SetActive (true);
        }
    }
}
```

The final goal of the code is to display 2 sprites at the location the finger starts the touch, and stay there until the finger is on the screen.
The code works the first time, no problem, but when I try to touch the screen again in the sprite is still at the same exact position, or better: it is DRAWN at the same "old" position, while from the editor, i can see the actual position of the anchors is the right one

How do i solve this?
I also tried using `RectTransform.sizeDelta` and setting the position via `.localPosition` but i get the same issue

Also, when I try to use 2 fingers on the same side of the screen the sprite actually gets drawn where it should!

If you want to try a live version here's [the published app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ziocain.botarena)